# License specifier in Solidity documentation

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets, solidity-0.8.x

This is a line in Solidity's documentation:

> Machine-readable license specifiers are important in a setting where publishing the source code is the default."

What is meant here by **publishing the source code** and **machine-readable license specifier**?

Comment: See [SPDX](https://spdx.org/licenses/).

Comment: something like `// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT`

Answer (score 0):

Companies often make their smart contract code available publicly. This increases trust in the smart contract. Publishing the code means making the code available publicly.

Since making source code available always touches on legal problems with regards to copyright, the Solidity compiler encourages the use of machine-readable SPDX license identifiers. Every source file should start with a comment indicating its license:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
```

The compiler does not ignore this like other comments. That's what is meant by machine-readable